# How to format SPO Powershell output

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Need some assistance with modifing the output of
"**get-spositegroup -Site $site -Group $group.Title | select title, users**"
so that it will list all users on a separate line. The current output is shown in the picture below.

This cmd is part of a script that lists all of our SharePoint Online users for each group in each site collection. The end goal is to have it list the site collection, group name, and user name on each line and then export it to a csv.

[image: Current output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but how about something like this:

```
Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site $site -Group $group.Title | %{
  $t = $_.Title
  $_.Users | %{New-Object PSObject -property @{
      Title = $t
      User = $_
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've added another column (Site) but how do i make that column appear first?

Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site $site -Group $group.Title | %{
                $t = $_.Title
                $_.Users | %{
                    New-Object PSObject -property @{
                    Site = $site.url
                    User = $_
                    "Group Title" = $t
                
   }  
  }
 }